# Cast JsonObjectRequest to Request

Tags: java, android, generics, android-volley, abstract

I create a Request through a function which returns a generic Request type:

```
public final class SpecificRequestService extends RequestService<JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected Request<JSONObject> getRequest() {
        return new JsonObjectRequest(...);
    }
}
```

Parent class is abstract defining:

```
public abstract class RequestService<T> {
    protected abstract Request<T> getRequest();
}
```

I receive an incompatible type error:

> ```
> Required: Request <org.json.JSONObject>  
> Found: Request <?>
> ```

Hopwever, `JsonObjectRequest` extends `JsonRequest<JSONObject>` where `JsonRequest<T>` in turn extends `Request<T>`.

Why is the type in the subclass complaining?

Comment: Your code won't compile. In order to declare an abstract method in a class the class should be declared abstract. Also final classes cannot be extended.

Comment: I am sorry, parent class is indeed abstract, not final. My typo.

Comment: I don't see why it would not work. I tried to reproduce your problem by creating a equivalent hierarchy a dummy classes and I don't get that error. Perhaps there is some obscure detail in the hierarchy of the classes that you are using that were are missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently an inner anonymous class override causes the problem. I managed to fix it using a self-cast on the overriden function:

```
public final class SpecificRequestService extends RequestService<JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected Request<JSONObject> getRequest() {
        return (JsonObjectRequest) new JsonObjectRequest(...)
            {...};
    }
}
```

I did not know this particular quirk of anonymous classes!

Comment: mmm it does not seem to make sense though... I mean, the cast does not seem to be doing anything. Doesn't give you any warnings? (e.g. "unchecked cast" or something like that)

Comment: What if you leave the cast out? is the inner class trick enough?

Comment: @ValentinRuano Leaving the cast out produces an error. Having the cast does not produce any "unchecked cast" errors...

Comment: I'm rather speachless.... can post the java compiler version that you are using (javac -version). If you are using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) could you try to compile it from the command line using javac?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce your issues using a bare-bone recreation of the class hierarchy that you are describing an I don't get a compilation error. So I'm assuming that there is something else in your case that were are missing.

I include my code here so that you can confirm that we are on the same page:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract R<T> getR();
}
final class B extends A<X> {
   public R<X> getR() {
      return new E();
   }
}
class D<T> extends R<T> {};
class E extends D<X> {};
class R<T> {}
class X {};
```

No compilation error using javac 1.8.x

Comment: This might be a `JsonObjectRequest` specific issue, but I managed to fix it with casting (for some reason). I post my answer below.